# Mac App Store Application Loader Exception

Tags: macos, cocoa, application-loader

I'm trying to send my pkg file to Apple, but it says :

> "There was a general exception while executing"
>
> "An exception has occured: null"

So what am I to do now :D? Any clues?
The only thing I did was download the new XCode so I could use iconutil to make a 1024x1024 icon, which seemed to work fine.

This is the error output in the console :

```
23/09/12 22:15:17,993 Application Loader:  Error:
[2012-09-23 22:14:48 CEST] <main>  INFO: Transporter is searching for updated software components.
[2012-09-23 22:14:52 CEST] <main>  INFO: Transporter is up-to-date.
[2012-09-23 22:14:53 CEST] <main>  INFO: MD5 checksum calculation in the transporter will be skipped.
[2012-09-23 22:14:53 CEST] <main>  INFO: Logging level set to eXtreme
[2012-09-23 22:14:53 CEST] <main>  INFO: Logging configured successfully.
[2012-09-23 22:14:53 CEST] <main> DEBUG: Attempting refresh of configuration data from https://contentdelivery.itunes.apple.com/transporter/Defaults.properties
[2012-09-23 22:14:54 CEST] <main> DEBUG: Configuration refresh successful.
[2012-09-23 22:14:54 CEST] <main> DEBUG: Saving configuration to local path: /Users/Home/.itmstransporter/Defaults.properties
[2012-09-23 22:14:54 CEST] <main>  INFO: iTMSTransporter : iTunes Store Transporter [1.7.5.1]
[2012-09-23 22:14:54 CEST] <main>  INFO: OS identifier: Mac OS X 10.7.5 (x86_64); jvm=20.10-b01-428; jre=1.6.0_35-b10-428-11M3811
[2012-09-23 22:14:54 CEST] <main>  INFO: Memory: [JVM] 21M free, 31M total, 1011M max [System] (Physical) 445M free, 4096M total (Swap) 216M free, 256M total
[2012-09-23 22:14:54 CEST] <main>  INFO: Client: Application Loader 2.7 (273)
[2012-09-23 22:14:54 CEST] <main>  INFO: Upload mode selected.
java.util.zip.ZipException: ZIP_Read: error reading zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1200(ZipFile.java:31)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:459)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.fill(ZipFile.java:242)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:256)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:90)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.copyStreamToFile(BundleCache.java:328)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarContent.extractEmbeddedJar(JarContent.java:471)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarContent.getEntryAsContent(JarContent.java:266)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.calculateContentPath(ModuleImpl.java:595)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.initializeContentPath(ModuleImpl.java:546)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.getContentPath(ModuleImpl.java:532)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$800(ModuleImpl.java:71)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleImpl.java:1810)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:727)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:71)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1768)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.getClassByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:645)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.resolver.WireImpl.getClass(WireImpl.java:99)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.searchImports(ModuleImpl.java:1390)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:722)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:71)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1768)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.apple.transporter.operation.Verify.dealWithIgnorablePackagesInPackagePath(Verify.java:615)
    at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.performUploadRequest(Upload.java:77)
    at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.performRequest(Upload.java:883)
    at com.apple.transporter.operation.Verify.execute(Verify.java:85)
    at com.apple.transporter.Application.begin(Application.java:149)
    at com.apple.transporter.osgi.TransporterService.run(TransporterService.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.apple.transporter.osgi.OSGiBootstrapper.runTransporter(OSGiBootstrapper.java:399)
    at com.apple.transporter.osgi.OSGiBootstrapper.bootstrap(OSGiBootstrapper.java:233)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.apple.transporter.FrameworkLoader.start(FrameworkLoader.java:143)
    at com.apple.transporter.Application.main(Application.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.webobjects._bootstrap.WOBootstrap.main(WOBootstrap.java:71)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to open JAR file, probably deleted: error in opening zip file
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarContent.openZipFile(JarContent.java:489)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarContent.<init>(JarContent.java:63)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarContent.getEntryAsContent(JarContent.java:275)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.calculateContentPath(ModuleImpl.java:595)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.initializeContentPath(ModuleImpl.java:546)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.getContentPath(ModuleImpl.java:532)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$800(ModuleImpl.java:71)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleImpl.java:1810)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:727)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:71)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1768)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.getClassByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:645)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.resolver.WireImpl.getClass(WireImpl.java:99)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.searchImports(ModuleImpl.java:1390)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:722)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:71)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1768)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.apple.transporter.operation.Verify.dealWithIgnorablePackagesInPackagePath(Verify.java:615)
    at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.performUploadRequest(Upload.java:77)
    at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.performRequest(Upload.java:883)
    at com.apple.transporter.operation.Verify.execute(Verify.java:85)
    at com.apple.transporter.Application.begin(Application.java:149)
    at com.apple.transporter.osgi.TransporterService.run(TransporterService.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.apple.transporter.osgi.OSGiBootstrapper.runTransporter(OSGiBootstrapper.java:399)
    at com.apple.transporter.osgi.OSGiBootstrapper.bootstrap(OSGiBootstrapper.java:233)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.apple.transporter.FrameworkLoader.start(FrameworkLoader.java:143)
    at com.apple.transporter.Application.main(Application.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.webobjects._bootstrap.WOBootstrap.main(WOBootstrap.java:71)
[2012-09-23 22:15:15 CEST] <main> ERROR: There was a general exception while executing
[2012-09-23 22:15:15 CEST] <main> ERROR: An exception has occurred: null
[2012-09-23 22:15:15 CEST] <main> DEBUG: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleImpl.java:1813)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:727)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:71)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1768)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.getClassByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:645)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.resolver.WireImpl.getClass(WireImpl.java:99)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.searchImports(ModuleImpl.java:1390)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:722)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:71)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1768)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.apple.transporter.operation.Verify.dealWithIgnorablePackagesInPackagePath(Verify.java:615)
    at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.performUploadRequest(Upload.java:77)
    at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.performRequest(Upload.java:883)
    at com.apple.transporter.operation.Verify.execute(Verify.java:85)
    at com.apple.transporter.Application.begin(Application.java:149)
    at com.apple.transporter.osgi.TransporterService.run(TransporterService.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.apple.transporter.osgi.OSGiBootstrapper.runTransporter(OSGiBootstrapper.java:399)
    at com.apple.transporter.osgi.OSGiBootstrapper.bootstrap(OSGiBootstrapper.java:233)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.apple.transporter.FrameworkLoader.start(FrameworkLoader.java:143)
    at com.apple.transporter.Application.main(Application.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.webobjects._bootstrap.WOBootstrap.main(WOBootstrap.java:71)

[2012-09-23 22:15:16 CEST] <main> DBG-X: Returning 1
23/09/12 22:15:17,995 Application Loader:  Out:
ERROR: Unable to extract embedded JAR file. (java.util.zip.ZipException: ZIP_Read: error reading zip file)
ERROR: Unable to get module class path. (java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to open JAR file, probably deleted: error in opening zip file)
```

Answer (score 11):

I asked this to Apple. They were very kind, this was their answer :

1) rename ~/.itmstransporter/ to ~/old.itmstransporter/

2) attempt upload

3) if upload succeeds, go ahead and delete ~/old.itmstransporter/

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been having issues with application loader and java for years and finally had to deal with it, this worked. Here was my error message, hopefully if someone else searches it this will come up because it returned nothing for me. An error occurred while trying to start the updater service. Exception's name: java.lang.NullPointerException, Exception's message: serviceReferences parameter cannot be null
An error occurred while trying to start transporter. Exception's name: java.lang.NullPointerException, Exception's message: serviceReferences parameter cannot be null

Comment: where to find this file?

Comment: Thanks @Fatso, that fixed my problem. Here is the extract from my log: [iTMSTransporter] java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[iTMSTransporter]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[iTMSTransporter]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[iTMSTransporter]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[iTMSTransporter]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

Comment: I wonder why this isn't marked as an answer...
Anyways, This solved my problem. Kudos @Fatso. You saved my day. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

I had this same error.  I changed my version number and not the build number.  As soon as I changed the build number, it went through.