# Error while uploading build in AppStore iOS

Tags: objective-c, itunes-store

While uploading build to Appstore, I am getting this error, Please help.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to open JAR file, probably deleted: error in opening zip file
at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarContent.openZipFile(JarContent.java:489)
at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarContent.<init>(JarContent.java:63)
at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarContent.getEntryAsContent(JarContent.java:275)
at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.calculateContentPath(ModuleImpl.java:595)
at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.initializeContentPath(ModuleImpl.java:546)
at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.getContentPath(ModuleImpl.java:532)
at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$800(ModuleImpl.java:71)
at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleImpl.java:1810)
at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:727)
at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:71)
at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1768)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.getClassByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:645)
at org.apache.felix.framework.resolver.WireImpl.getClass(WireImpl.java:99)
at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.searchImports(ModuleImpl.java:1390)
at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:722)
at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:71)
at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1768)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at com.apple.transporter.softwaresupport.SoftwareSupportBundleActivator.registerService(SoftwareSupportBundleActivator.java:22)
at com.apple.transporter.softwaresupport.SoftwareSupportBundleActivator.start(SoftwareSupportBundleActivator.java:15)
at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:629)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1827)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1744)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:922)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:909)
at com.apple.transporter.osgi.OSGiBootstrapper.startBundle(OSGiBootstrapper.java:522)
at com.apple.transporter.osgi.OSGiBootstrapper.bootstrap(OSGiBootstrapper.java:297)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.apple.transporter.Application.start(Application.java:133)
at com.apple.transporter.Application.main(Application.java:357)
```

An error occurred while starting bundles for the software update process.  Transporter will try to continue.  Activator start error in bundle com.apple.transporter.softwaresupport [8].
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to open JAR file, probably deleted: error in opening zip file
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarContent.openZipFile(JarContent.java:489)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarContent.(JarContent.java:63)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarContent.getEntryAsContent(JarContent.java:275)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.calculateContentPath(ModuleImpl.java:595)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.initializeContentPath(ModuleImpl.java:546)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.getContentPath(ModuleImpl.java:532)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$800(ModuleImpl.java:71)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleImpl.java:1810)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:727)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:71)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1768)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.getClassByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:645)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.resolver.WireImpl.getClass(WireImpl.java:99)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.searchImports(ModuleImpl.java:1390)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:722)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:71)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1768)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at com.apple.transporter.softwaresupport.SoftwareSupportBundleActivator.registerService(SoftwareSupportBundleActivator.java:22)
    at com.apple.transporter.softwaresupport.SoftwareSupportBundleActivator.start(SoftwareSupportBundleActivator.java:15)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:629)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1827)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1744)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:922)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:909)
    at com.apple.transporter.osgi.OSGiBootstrapper.startBundle(OSGiBootstrapper.java:522)
    at com.apple.transporter.osgi.OSGiBootstrapper.bootstrap(OSGiBootstrapper.java:297)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.apple.transporter.Application.start(Application.java:133)
    at com.apple.transporter.Application.main(Application.java:357)
An error occurred while starting bundles for the software update process.  Transporter will try to continue.  Activator start error in bundle com.apple.transporter.softwaresupport [9].
[2017-02-07 15:54:03 IST]   INFO: Transporter is searching for updated software components.
[2017-02-07 15:54:07 IST]   INFO: Transporter is up-to-date.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to open JAR file, probably deleted: error in opening zip file
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarContent.openZipFile(JarContent.java:489)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarContent.(JarContent.java:63)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarContent.getEntryAsContent(JarContent.java:275)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.calculateContentPath(ModuleImpl.java:595)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.initializeContentPath(ModuleImpl.java:546)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.getContentPath(ModuleImpl.java:532)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$800(ModuleImpl.java:71)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleImpl.java:1810)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:727)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:71)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1768)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.getClassByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:645)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.resolver.WireImpl.getClass(WireImpl.java:99)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.searchImports(ModuleImpl.java:1390)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:722)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:71)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1768)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at com.apple.transporter.osgi.TransporterService.run(TransporterService.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.apple.transporter.osgi.OSGiBootstrapper.runTransporter(OSGiBootstrapper.java:579)
    at com.apple.transporter.osgi.OSGiBootstrapper.bootstrap(OSGiBootstrapper.java:305)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.apple.transporter.Application.start(Application.java:133)
    at com.apple.transporter.Application.main(Application.java:357)
An error occurred while trying to start transporter. Exception's name: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException, Exception's message: null

ERROR: Unable to get module class path. (java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to open JAR file, probably deleted: error in opening zip file)
ERROR: Unable to get module class path. (java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to open JAR file, probably deleted: error in opening zip file)
ERROR: Unable to get module class path. (java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to open JAR file, probably deleted: error in opening zip file)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562879/mac-app-store-application-loader-exception

Comment: I got this answer, but how to do this, can you please detail: 
rename ~/.itmstransporter/ to ~/old.itmstransporter/